# "Missing XML tag" Error in Google Webmaster Tools Using Sitemap From Yoast SEO Tools

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Yoast SEO Tools plugin on a WordPress site. I attempted to submit the XML sitemap it generates to Google Webmaster Tools, but I am getting an error, "Missing XML tag". The plugin doesn't actually generate a sitemap file anymore, so I am not sure how to address this issue. Anyone else familiar with this issue, and/or how to address it?

Comment: I was also face same issue , In case my site map was empty , so make sure your site has atleast one url.

Answer (score 2):

As it says here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35738?hl=en, check that your XML sitemap is not showing empty lines.

Or, as they say:

> To fix this issue, review your Sitemap carefully against the [Sitemap
>   guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=183668). (**The error message includes the problematic tag and the
>   line number where the problem was found.**) Then upload and resubmit
>   your updated Sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submitting the main index Sitemap URL:

```
/sitemap_index.xml
```

I had to submit each "sub" sitemap separately to get no errors.

```
/page-sitemap.xml
/post-sitemap.xml
/custom-post-type-sitemap.xml
```

Comment: same for me, but submitting them separately also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I see a possible reason for those missing xml tags...

I came here because I had the same problem for some of my sub-sitemaps on my website:

http://www.JouVoordeel.be/sitemap-pt-page-2012-09.xml

http://www.JouVoordeel.be/sitemap-pt-page-2014-09.xml

As you can see they are both sitemaps for PAGES. When I looked at those pages I noticed that they were redirected to another URL in my website, so I think this redirecting causes the errors.

I use a plugin called 'page links to'

Options:
- remove the URL-redirection from the page
- exclude the page from the sitemap (don't know how)
- 'Google xml sitemaps' authors should fix this.